# Confusion while uploading the csv file in R

Tags: r

a=read.csv("delivery_time.csv",TRUE,",")

is the line of code but the error message

Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
cannot open file 'delivery_time.csv': No such file or directory

Comment: The file is not in your working directory. Use `getwd()` to see what folder/directory R is currently using. use `a <- read.csv(file.choose(), TRUE)` to search interactively for the file and select it.

Comment: Also, header = TRUE and sep = "," are the defaults for read.csv so there is no point in specifying these arguments.